# Error while installing kubectl in Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, installation, kubectl, chocolatey

Installing the kubectl on windows 10 not working. I follow this [URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-kubectl.html).

I tried different install options, in the powershell and using chocolote. None of them worked for me. The error is clear that this execuable is not supported for windows os. I did checked the SHA but it is different.

```
PS D:\chocoloate_tmpdir> curl -o kubectl.exe.sha256 https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.14.6/2019-08-22/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe.sha256
PS D:\chocoloate_tmpdir> Get-FileHash kubectl.exe                                                                                                                                               
Algorithm       Hash                                                                   Path
---------       ----                                                                   ----
SHA256          02F984988E490046CBC831A582D34505C28C7DD9AB61C357E264C7178596B701       D:\chocoloate_tmpdir\kubectl.exe

PS D:\chocoloate_tmpdir> Get-FileHash .\kubectl.exe.sha256                                                                                                                                      
Algorithm       Hash                                                                   Path
---------       ----                                                                   ----
SHA256          98BCEB6AF839704828C28709B60628E25CF5F624A6D6E7D06F1FC255AA4254CB       D:\chocoloate_tmpdir\kubectl.exe.sha256
```

question is, what could be the issue and what other methods are available for installing kubectl in windows.

Here are the commands tried and error output:

**one:**

```
PS D:\chocoloate_tmpdir> choco install kubernetes-cli                                                                                                                                           Chocolatey v0.10.15
Installing the following packages:
kubernetes-cli
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading kubernetes-cli 1.17.1... 100%

kubernetes-cli v1.17.1 [Approved]
kubernetes-cli package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
The package kubernetes-cli wants to run 'chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider:
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
Do you want to run the script?([Y]es/[A]ll - yes to all/[N]o/[P]rint): Y

Extracting 64-bit C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-cli\tools\kubernetes-client-windows-amd64.tar.gz to C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-cli\tools...
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-cli\tools
Extracting 64-bit C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-cli\tools\kubernetes-client-windows-amd64.tar to C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-cli\tools...
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-cli\tools
 ShimGen has successfully created a shim for kubectl.exe
 The install of kubernetes-cli was successful.
  Software installed to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-cli\tools'

Chocolatey installed 1/1 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
PS D:\chocoloate_tmpdir> kubectl version --client                                                                                                                                               Program 'kubectl.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1 char:1
+ kubectl version --client
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ kubectl version --client
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

**two:**

```
PS D:\chocoloate_tmpdir> curl -o kubectl.exe https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.14.6/2019-08-22/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe 
PS D:\chocoloate_tmpdir> cp .\kubectl.exe C:\bin\ 
PS D:\chocoloate_tmpdir> kubectl version                                                                                                                                                        Program 'kubectl.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1 char:1
+ kubectl version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ kubectl version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Comment: found the issue. calling the ./kubectl.exe does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably missed some of these steps:

> Copy the binary to a folder in your  `PATH`. If you have an existing
>   directory in your PATH that you use for command line utilities, copy
>   the binary to that directory. Otherwise, complete the following steps.
>
> 1. Create a new directory for your command line binaries, such as  `C:\bin`.
> 2. Copy the  `kubectl.exe`  binary to your new directory.
> 3. Edit your user or system PATH environment variable to add the new directory to your PATH.
> 4. Close your PowerShell terminal and open a new one to pick up the new PATH variable.

Please verify what is the current content of your PATH. You can move your `kubectl` binary directly to one of those folders which are already added to your PATH. Alternatively you may edit it and add your desired directory containing `kubectl`. Have you relaunched your **PowerShell terminal** after saving the changes ? It's quite straightforward to configure and there is no need to use full paths to the executable.

Take a look at [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows) article in the official kubernetes docs.

Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the command from the current path does the trick. I have added the executable to c:\bin path and added the path to system environment variable, somehow it was not set, not sure why. Its an issue with the execuable being not found in the path.

```
PS D:\chocoloate_tmpdir> kubectl version                                                                                                                                                        Program 'kubectl.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1 char:1
+ kubectl version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ kubectl version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

PS D:\chocoloate_tmpdir> .\kubectl.exe version                                                                                                                                                  Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14+", GitVersion:"v1.14.7-eks-1861c5", GitCommit:"1861c597586f84f1498a9f2151c78d8a6bf47814", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-24T22:12:08Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and this is basically due to the system path issue. If you have kubectl exe placed in different location then this could cause the error. When you run the kuebctl on the command line then the system fail to read kubectl exe file.

steps that can be followed to fix this issue :

1. Check whether you have kubectl in different location added in the environment variable "PATH"
2. Clean all the kubectl exe files and place it in one location then map that location in the env "PATH"
3. Restart your terminal and open a new terminal to test this

Hope this would fix the issue